# Not able to SSH to the VM using Parmiko Python module

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, paramiko, ssh-keys

I would like to ssh to one VM and do some command execution. The VM which I tried to SSH is having a private key authentication and a passphrase to login. Here am used Paramiko python module, but getting saved_exception with error reason:

> paramiko.BadAuthenticationType: Bad authentication type (allowed_types=['publickey', 'gssapi-keyex', 'gssapi-with-mic'])

Am tried here with username, and password as passphrase and given private key file as key_file (also tried publick key) but not able to establish the connection.

The code tried is given below:

```
from paramiko import client

class ssh:
    client = None

    def __init__ (self, server_addr,username, password, keyfile):
            print ("Establishing VM connection")

            #Create ssh client.
            self.client = client.SSHClient ()

            ## The following line is required if you want the script to be able to access a server that's not yet in the known_hosts.
            self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy (client.AutoAddPolicy())

            #Make the connection.
            self.client.connect (server_addr, username=username, password=password, key_filename=keyfile);

    def sendCommand (self, command):
            #Check if connection is made successfully.
            if (self.client) :
                    stdin,stdout,stderr = self.client.exec_command (command)
                    while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready ():
                            alldata = stdout.channel.recv (1024)
                            while stdout.channel.recv_ready ():
                                    alldata += stdout.channel.recv(1024)

                            print (str(alldata))
            else:
                    print "Connection is not opened"
```

Comment: Password is not passphrase. For a start, remove the passphrase from the key and try to login with the key only (no password or passphrase). Does that work? - Actually can you even login using a standalone SSH client? Like PuTTY? Show us its event log!

Comment: Am able to ssh to this machine when tried from shell. But still betting authentication failure from python script. Getting the below warning like unknown ssh-rsa host key for the tried VM, `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py:95: UserWarning: Unknown ssh-rsa host key for`

Comment: So show us `ssh -v ...` output + Did you try the key without passphrase?